# Combine two SQL Tables with a where Variable

Tags: php, sql, join, where-clause

Can't seem to get it right. I am trying to join two tables in my form and the WHERE is a variable taken from the URL (www.websiste.com?reference=38)

Both tables have the same commonkey (ProgramCode)

Table 1: programs:
id_program | ProgramName |  ReleaseDate | ProgramCode

Table 2: ProgramGenre:
id_program_genre | ProgramCode | id_genre

I got this but its not working

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM program
                        INNER JOIN ProgramGenre
                            ON program.ProgramCode = ProgramGenre.ProgramCode               
                    WHERE ProgramCode='$_GET[reference]'";
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: How is it not working?  Edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: You might need to specify the table name in your `where` clause, depending on your SQL engine, eg `WHERE program.ProgramCode='$_GET[reference]'";`.  But please read up on [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) - that's dangerous code

Comment: Thanks @Hobo. Changing the line for the 'where' fixed it. Working perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem - but please don't ignore my comment about SQL injection.  A malicious user could pass a dodgy value and do things like deleting your data or dropping your database.

Comment: Yes was looking into that before as well, now i am using PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
$sql_select="SELECT * from programs p,ProgramGenre g where p.ProgramCode=g.ProgramCode and p.ProgramCode='".$_REQUEST['reference']."'";
```

or you can use

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM programs
                        INNER JOIN ProgramGenre
                            ON programs.ProgramCode = ProgramGenre.ProgramCode               
                    WHERE ProgramCode='".$_GET['reference']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't know which column `ProgramCode` refers to.

Assuming a parametrized query,

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM program
                    INNER JOIN ProgramGenre
                        ON program.ProgramCode = ProgramGenre.ProgramCode               
                WHERE program.ProgramCode=?";
```